# Перевод HTML разметки Nazox под React.js

Tags: css, jquery, reactjs, html5, bootstrap

Всем привет. Имеется разметка HTML написанная на основе шаблона Nazox. Нужно переделать под React.js. Уже пробовал просто конвертировать HTML в JSX и подключить нужные библиотеки. Но нет должного результата. 
Вот к слову разметка HTML:

```
<!doctype html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Асосӣ</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta content="Premium Multipurpose Admin & Dashboard Template" name="description" />
    <meta content="Themesdesign" name="author" />
    <!-- App favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/favicon.ico">

    <!-- jquery.vectormap css -->
    <link href="assets/libs/admin-resources/jquery.vectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />

    <!-- DataTables -->
    <link href="assets/libs/datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- Responsive datatable examples -->
    <link href="assets/libs/datatables.net-responsive-bs4/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />

    <!-- Bootstrap Css -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" id="bootstrap-style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Icons Css -->
    <link href="assets/css/icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- App Css-->
    <link href="assets/css/app.css" id="app-style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body data-layout="horizontal">
    <div id="layout-wrapper">
        <!-- Begin page -->
        
        <header id="page-topbar" style="position: static  !important;;">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <div class="d-flex">
                    <!-- LOGO -->
                    <div class="navbar-brand-box">
                        <a href="index.html" class="logo logo-dark">
                            <span class="logo-sm">
                                <img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="" height="22">
                            </span>
                            <span class="logo-lg">
                                <img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="" height="50">
                            </span>
                        </a>

                        <a href="index.html" class="logo logo-light">
                            <span class="logo-sm">
                                <img src="assets/images/logo-sm-light.png" alt="" height="22">
                            </span>
                            <span class="logo-lg">
                                <img src="assets/images/logo-light.png" alt="" height="20">
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row navbar-header main-navbar" style="justify-content: center !important;">
                    <div class="current-menu">
                        <a class="navbar_link" href="admin.html">
                            <button type="button" class="btn nav-item waves-effect">
                                <i class=" ri-home-4-line"></i>
                                <span>Асосӣ</span>
                           </button>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div>
                        <a class="navbar_link" href="groups.html">
                           <button type="button" class="btn nav-item waves-effect">
                                <i class=" ri-file-list-line"></i>
                                <span>Гурӯҳҳо</span>
                            </button>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <a class="navbar_link" href="users.html">
                            <button type="button" class="btn nav-item waves-effect">
                                    <i class="ri-account-circle-line"></i>
                                    <span>Кормандон</span>
                            </button>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <a class="navbar_link" href="currency.html">
                            <button type="button" class="btn nav-item waves-effect">
                                <i class="ri-money-dollar-circle-line"></i>
                                <span>Асъор</span>
                            </button>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex">
                    <div class="dropdown d-inline-block">   
                        <button class="btn button_blue btn-primary w-md waves-effect waves-light waves-effect" type="submit">
                            <i class="ri-logout-box-r-line"></i>
                            Баромад
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </header>
        
        <div class="container-fluid mt-lg-5 mt-3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body" style="position: relative;">
                    <h3 class="text-center"  style="color: #3f41b5;font-weight: 700;">Харид ва фурӯши даруна</h3>
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-0">

                            <thead style="background-color: #3f41b5; color:white">
                                <tr>
                                    <th rowspan="2" class="text-center">Шаҳр, ноҳия</th>
                                    <th colspan="2" class="text-center">1 USD</th>
                                    <th colspan="2" class="text-center">10 RUB</th>
                                    <th colspan="2" class="text-center">1 EUR</th>
                                    <th colspan="2" class="text-center">UZB</th>
                                    <th colspan="2" class="text-center">KAZ</th>
                                    <th colspan="2" class="text-center">KGZ</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr >
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        <div class="badge badge-soft-warning font-size-15" style="vertical-align: bottom;">Харид <i class="ri-arrow-down-line"></i></div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        <div class="badge badge-soft-success font-size-15" style="vertical-align: bottom;">Фурӯш <i class="ri-arrow-up-line"></i></div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        <div class="badge badge-soft-warning font-size-15" style="vertical-align: bottom;">Харид <i class="ri-arrow-down-line"></i></div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        <div class="badge badge-soft-success font-size-15" style="vertical-align: bottom;">Фурӯш <i class="ri-arrow-up-line"></i></div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        <div class="badge badge-soft-warning font-size-15" style="vertical-align: bottom;">Харид <i class="ri-arrow-down-line"></i></div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        <div class="badge badge-soft-success font-size-15" style="vertical-align: bottom;">Фурӯш <i class="ri-arrow-up-line"></i></div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        <div class="badge badge-soft-warning font-size-15" style="vertical-align: bottom;">Харид <i class="ri-arrow-down-line"></i></div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        <div class="badge badge-soft-success font-size-15" style="vertical-align: bottom;">Фурӯш <i class="ri-arrow-up-line"></i></div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        <div class="badge badge-soft-warning font-size-15" style="vertical-align: bottom;">Харид <i class="ri-arrow-down-line"></i></div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        <div class="badge badge-soft-success font-size-15" style="vertical-align: bottom;">Фурӯш <i class="ri-arrow-up-line"></i></div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        <div class="badge badge-soft-warning font-size-15" style="vertical-align: bottom;">Харид <i class="ri-arrow-down-line"></i></div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        <div class="badge badge-soft-success font-size-15" style="vertical-align: bottom;">Фурӯш <i class="ri-arrow-up-line"></i></div>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr class="table-info1">
                                    <td class="text-center ">Хатлон</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">10.95</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">10.96</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.118</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.123</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">11.7</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">12</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.09</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.1</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.2</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.25</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">1</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">1.2</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="text-center ">Хуҷанд</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">10.95</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">10.96</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.118</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.123</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">11.7</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">12</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.09</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.1</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.2</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.25</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">1</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">1.2</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="table-info1">
                                    <td class="text-center ">Айнӣ</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">10.95</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">10.96</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.118</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.123</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">11.7</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">12</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.09</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.1</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.2</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.25</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">1</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">1.2</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="text-center ">Б.Ғафуров</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">10.95</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">10.96</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.118</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.123</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">11.7</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">12</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.09</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.1</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.2</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.25</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">1</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">1.2</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body" style="position: relative;">
                    <h3 class="text-center"  style="color: #3f41b5;font-weight: 700;">Харид ва фурӯши беруна</h3>
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-0">

                            <thead style="background-color: #3f41b5; color:white">
                                <tr>
                                    <th rowspan="2" class="text-center">Шаҳр, ноҳия</th>
                                    <th colspan="2" class="text-center">1 USD</th>
                                    <th colspan="2" class="text-center">10 RUB</th>
                                    <th colspan="2" class="text-center">1 EUR</th>
                                    <th colspan="2" class="text-center">UZB</th>
                                    <th colspan="2" class="text-center">KAZ</th>
                                    <th colspan="2" class="text-center">KGZ</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr >
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        <div class="badge badge-soft-warning font-size-15" style="vertical-align: bottom;">Харид <i class="ri-arrow-down-line"></i></div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        <div class="badge badge-soft-success font-size-15" style="vertical-align: bottom;">Фурӯш <i class="ri-arrow-up-line"></i></div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        <div class="badge badge-soft-warning font-size-15" style="vertical-align: bottom;">Харид <i class="ri-arrow-down-line"></i></div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        <div class="badge badge-soft-success font-size-15" style="vertical-align: bottom;">Фурӯш <i class="ri-arrow-up-line"></i></div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        <div class="badge badge-soft-warning font-size-15" style="vertical-align: bottom;">Харид <i class="ri-arrow-down-line"></i></div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        <div class="badge badge-soft-success font-size-15" style="vertical-align: bottom;">Фурӯш <i class="ri-arrow-up-line"></i></div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        <div class="badge badge-soft-warning font-size-15" style="vertical-align: bottom;">Харид <i class="ri-arrow-down-line"></i></div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        <div class="badge badge-soft-success font-size-15" style="vertical-align: bottom;">Фурӯш <i class="ri-arrow-up-line"></i></div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        <div class="badge badge-soft-warning font-size-15" style="vertical-align: bottom;">Харид <i class="ri-arrow-down-line"></i></div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        <div class="badge badge-soft-success font-size-15" style="vertical-align: bottom;">Фурӯш <i class="ri-arrow-up-line"></i></div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        <div class="badge badge-soft-warning font-size-15" style="vertical-align: bottom;">Харид <i class="ri-arrow-down-line"></i></div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        <div class="badge badge-soft-success font-size-15" style="vertical-align: bottom;">Фурӯш <i class="ri-arrow-up-line"></i></div>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr class="table-info1">
                                    <td class="text-center ">Хатлон</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">10.95</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">10.96</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.118</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.123</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">11.7</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">12</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.09</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.1</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.2</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.25</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">1</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">1.2</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="text-center ">Хуҷанд</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">10.95</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">10.96</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.118</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.123</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">11.7</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">12</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.09</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.1</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.2</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.25</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">1</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">1.2</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="table-info1">
                                    <td class="text-center ">Айнӣ</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">10.95</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">10.96</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.118</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.123</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">11.7</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">12</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.09</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.1</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.2</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.25</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">1</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">1.2</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="text-center ">Б.Ғафуров</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">10.95</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">10.96</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.118</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.123</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">11.7</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">12</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.09</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.1</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.2</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">0.25</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">1</td>
                                    <td class="text-center">1.2</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- end card body-->
        </div>
        <footer class="footer">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    &copy;Copyright MiNiM Team
                    Вақт дар сервер<br>
                    <script>
                        document.write(new Date())
                    </script>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
        <!-- ============================================================== -->
        <!-- Start right Content here -->
        <!-- ============================================================== -->
        <!-- end main content-->

        <!-- END layout-wrapper -->

        <!-- /Right-bar -->

        <!-- Right bar overlay-->
        <div class="rightbar-overlay"></div>

    </div><!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
    
    <script src="assets/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/libs/metismenu/metisMenu.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/libs/simplebar/simplebar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/libs/node-waves/waves.min.js"></script>

    <!-- apexcharts -->
    <script src="assets/libs/apexcharts/apexcharts.min.js"></script>

    <!-- jquery.vectormap map -->
    <script src="assets/libs/admin-resources/jquery.vectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/libs/admin-resources/jquery.vectormap/maps/jquery-jvectormap-us-merc-en.js"></script>

    <!-- Required datatable js -->
    <script src="assets/libs/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/libs/datatables.net-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Responsive examples -->
    <script src="assets/libs/datatables.net-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/libs/datatables.net-responsive-bs4/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

    <script src="assets/js/pages/dashboard.init.js"></script>

    <script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Вот то, что я сконвертировал:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min";
import './styles/icons.css';
import './styles/app.css';
import './libs/admin-resources/jquery.vectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css';
import './styles/icons.min.css';
export default class Page extends Component {
    render()
    {
      return(
        <div>
             //Конвертированый HTML
          </div>
```

'''